# Kubernetes Prometheus: Add alert when container memory usage is greater than total kube node memory capacity

Tags: kubernetes, containers, prometheus

I am monitoring several kubernetes clusters with Prometheus.

I want an alert rule that fires, when the total container memory usage exceeds or is equal to the total kube node memory capacity.

What I constructed is the following:

```
sum(container_memory_usage_bytes{instance=~"sa.*.domain"}) >= sum(kube_node_status_capacity_memory_bytes{node=~"sa.*.domain"})
```

but in the expression evaluator in the Prometheus GUI I get a numerical value back when I test this expression.

Can someone help me with the right expression?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
rforberger

Comment: Did you add following query as alerting rule? https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/

Comment: @KFC_ No I didn't add it as an alerting rule yet. Do you think the rule works then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rebuild the query, and have a question regarding it. I will open another question.

Comment: So, is this question still open ? If not, can you remove it please ?

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA I answered my own question, so it should be closed now.